# How do I parse XML with mix of element and untagged text with serde-xml-rs?

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I have XML that in some parts mixes XML elements with untagged text.

```xml
<element>
    <subelement id="123"></subelement>
    arbitrary text
</element>
```

How can I parse that into a struct in Rust?

My implementation attempt:

```rust
use serde_derive::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_xml_rs::{from_str};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
#[serde(rename="element")]
struct Element {
    #[serde(default)]
    subelement: Option<SubElement>,
    #[serde(rename="$value")]
    text: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct SubElement {
    id: i32,
}

fn main() {
    const XML: &str = r#"
    <element>
        <subelement id="123"></subelement>
        arbitrary text
    </element>
    "#;
    let expected = Element {
        subelement: Some(SubElement { id: 123 }),
        text: String::from("arbitrary text"),
    };
    let actual: Element = from_str(&XML).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(&expected, &actual);
    println!("{:?}", &actual);
}
```

The error message:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { field: "duplicate field `$value`" }'
```

I also asked this question [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/parse-xml-with-mix-of-element-and-untagged-text/65549) a day ago.

Comment: Regarding the warning given while writing the question: It would help to better clarify what doesn't work. Ideally, show what the program is printing for those samples and state the expected results.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I was hoping to use quick-xml serde integration to parse some xml but it has mixed content text/tags in it.